# how do I find derivative of eigenvalues for real, symmetric, positive definite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a matrix valued-function $A(t)$ such that $A(t)$ is real, symmetric, and positive definite for all $t$,
I would like to obtain a differential equation over the variables $A(t),x(t),\lambda(t)$
whose solution is a matrix valued $A(t)$, a eigenvector-valued $x(t)$, and a real-eigenvalued $\lambda(t)$.

why I came across this problem:
I obtained a $3\times 3$ covariance matrix solution by solving  differential equation with 3 variables. I need to fix the solution by tracking eigenvalues of matrices

Edit 1: Does it become any simpler if we use only $A(t)$ and $\lambda(t)$ as variables and remove $x(t)$ from consideration?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}\lambda(t)=\langle x(t),A^\prime(t) x(t)\rangle$.

Comment: @julian how did you derive the equation?

Comment: the heuristic way is to differentiate $\lambda(t)=\langle x(t),A(t)x(t)\rangle$ with the product rule. the rigorous way is explained in Kato's book on perturbation theory.

Comment: @j.deo Based on your context, it sounds like you already have a differential equation over $A$ whose solution is $A(t)$.  Can we assume that we have such an equation from which to construct the D.E. that you're looking for? Does the DE from which you got the covariance matrix have a particular form (e.g. is it a linear differential equation)?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I obtained mean and covariance as a solution of three variable DE thought a process called escalator boxcar train method. Mean I obtained is correct. The problem is with 3 x 3 covariance matrix. To fix the covariance I need to track Eigenvalues of that matrix. The DE from which I got the covariance matrix is Linear differential equation with 3 varables.